# Vaadin 7 + Spring: no ContextLoaderListener registered?

Tags: java, spring, vaadin7

I am trying to get Spring to initialize a single bean for me.  Note that I am not interested in a dispatcher (I think), since I don't care about having the Vaadin components themselves init'd by Spring.

Here is what I have so far:

**web.xml:**

```
<web-app
  id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:spring-context.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>TAM</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sgss.tam.web.MainUI</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TAM</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/tam/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**spring-context.xml:**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs
        http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd
    ">

    <!-- Turn on AspectJ @Configurable support -->
    <context:spring-configured />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sgss.tam" />

    <!-- Turn on @Autowired, @PostConstruct etc support -->
    <bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
    <bean
    class="org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="envVars" class="com.sgss.tam.service.EnvironmentVars">
        <property name="workflowEngineUrl" value="fafafaf"></property>
        <property name="userAuthenticationUrl" value="fofofo"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

The point of this exercise is simply to have com.sgss.tam.service.EnvironmentVars configured by Spring.  If that can work, then I should be able to access this bean in my UI subclass, by implementing WebApplicationInitializer thusly:

```
@Override
public void onStartup(final ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    final ApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
    final EnvironmentVars envVars = context.getBean("envVars", EnvironmentVars.class);
}
```

**However...**

Instead, when executing the code above in onStartup, here is what actually happens:

```
2015-02-24 15:53:34.814:INFO:/:main: Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [com.sgss.tam.web.MainUI@30b1a21d]
2015-02-24 15:53:42.706:WARN:oeja.ServletContainerInitializersStarter:main: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:90)
    at com.sgss.tam.web.MainUI.onStartup(MainUI.java:69)
```

as if I has not defined a listener in web.xml.

If I change the listener-class to something non-existent, then I see an appropriate error message informing me that that class is not found, which demonstrates that this configuration is actually being parsed.  So why is there no Spring context?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well, three days later, here is my solution:

First of all, I ditched web.xml in favor of the Vaadin 7-style annotations on my UI subclass, thusly:

```
@WebServlet(initParams = { //
        @WebInitParam(name = "contextConfigLocation", value = "/WEB-INF/applicationConfiguration.xml") //
}, value = { "/tam/*", "/VAADIN/*" }, asyncSupported = true)
@VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = MainUI.class, widgetset = "com.sgss.AppWidgetSet")
public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
}
```

Note that it matters not what I put for the value of the "contextConfigLocation" init var here... Jetty will happily ignore this value and load /WEB-INF/applicationConfiguration.xml anyway.  But it must be present.
So I renamed and moved the above spring-context.xml to correspond to this.

Then, for my implementation of WebApplicationInitializer in MainUI:

```
@Override
public void onStartup(final ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    final ContextLoaderListener listener = servletContext.createListener(ContextLoaderListener.class);
    listener.initWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
    final ApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
    environmentVars = context.getBean("envVars", EnvironmentVars.class);
}
```

Where `environmentVars` is a static variable in MainUI.

Simple, right?